# Write file in java

Tags: java, string

```
String fileNameTemp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyy").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

final String filePath = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getParent()+"\\"+fileNameTemp+fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getName()+ ".Mp_Lgr2";

FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);

BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
```

Value of  `fileNameTemp` is "290313_4_X634866925_testtemperature9"

If i dont re  fix value of `fileNameTemp = "290313_4_X634866925_testtemperature9"`

it will be error at `new FileOutputStream(filePath)`: `File not found Exception`
But if i set value for `fileNameTemp="290313_4_X634866925_testtemperature9"`
it wil run 
I don't know why it is, Hope anybody can help me

Comment: I recommend reading this, if you haven't already: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/

Answer (score 0):

`fileNameTemp` should be equal to `290313`. I don't think you are building the path that you are expecting. Debug there.